# Linking .lib files compiling on cygwin

Tags: c++, opencv

I am having errors building a c++ file on Windows using cygwin and linking opencv .lib files. The .lib files are present in a directory called lib. Here is the command I am using to build a file called tracker.cpp. I am getting "undefined reference to" errors or "unable to find the library" errors after trying many combinations.

```
g++ -o ../bin/tracker -I../include tracker.cpp -L../lib -lopencv_core246d -lopencv_highgui246d -lopencv_imgproc246d -lopencv_objdetect246d
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't link ".lib" files with mingw, those .lib ones are for vs.

in 2.4.6, there should be a mingw folder with *.a or *.a.so files, use those

Comment: Thank you. Just realized that, :).